# Angular split json in javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here's my json :

```
[
    {
        "name": "1QQQJohnQQQ11_12_1998",
        "age" : "ads"
    },
    {
        "name": "2QQQEvaQQQ05_11_1989",
        "age" : "ads"
    },
    {
        "name": "3QQQCasperQQQ12_06_1994",
        "age" : "ads"
    },
    {
        "name": "4QQQBeanQQQ30_12_1996",
        "age" : "ads"
    }]
```

and javascript file :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.service('service', function($http, $q){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get("datesss.json").then(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            this.getNames = function(){
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });
        app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, service){
            var promise = service.getNames();
            promise.then(function(data){
                $scope.names = data.data;
                var namesplit = $scope.names
                namesplit.map(function(item) {
                    item.type = item.name.split('QQQ')[0];
                    item.date = item.name.split('QQQ')[1];
                    item.name = item.name.split('QQQ')[2];
                });
                console.log(namesplit);
                });
    });
```

I had to split name from json by "QQQ" in javascript file. In `console.log(namesplit)` i have everything ("type", "date", "name") listed good.

What i need to do is write "type", "date", and "name" in table. I tried this :

```
 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">type</th>
                            <th class="text-center">date</th>
                            <th class="text-center">name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="name in namesplit">
                            <td>{{name.type}}</td>
                            <td>{{name.date}}</td>
                            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

But it didn't work. Someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Namesplit is not a $scope variable, hence it only exists in your promise.

Comment: @Noppey Do you have any idea how to split json "name" in javascript file?

Answer (score 2):

Change all the occurrences of `namesplit` to `$scope.namesplit` in your controller.

Otherwise here, `ng-repeat="name in namesplit`", there is no scope variable called `namesplit`